# Como puedo aplicar unas formas con css y cambiar la información de una tabla al dar click al boton

Tags: wordpress

me gustaria saber si alguien a trabajado con diseño web en wordpress y con el maquetador elementor, tengo un asunto que resolver, en la primera seccion del home debo hacer una curva de la columna izquierda pero la forma en que lo hice fue con degradado de la seccion colocandola linea, sin embargo no me queda como debe ser, en el adjunto dejo un ejemplo de como deberia quedar y el como me ha quedado.

En segundo lugar el psd me muestra un boton para una tabla de precio en el cual al presionarlo cambia los valores de la tabla, la idea es que muestre tanto planes mensuales como anuales, adjunto tambien como deberia quedar.

este es el link del sitio https://oficinavirtuallaserena.cl/ los detalles que tengo solo es para resolverlos en el home[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías poner el código para que podamos ayudarte. Las preguntas sin código no son muy bien recibidas.

Comment: Saludos, el codigo lo estoy pasando en el mismo link de la pagina porque se trata de algo netamente front que algun colaborador puede inspeccionar el codigo y ver las clases css de la pagina, copiar todo ese html y css seria enredar el contenido, nose si me hago entender.

Comment: O sea que esperas que inspeccionemos el código de la página para que ENCONTREMOS la parte en la que tienes un error, y luego ADIVINEMOS CUAL ES EL ERROR, y para finalizar, LO RESOLVAMOS? Te recomiendo que revises [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que así tal vez alguien pueda ayudarte

Comment: ah ok, vale gracias por la recomendación, soy nuevo y pues ya se entonces que debo formular de nuevo bien la pregunta

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta en cualquier momento. También te invito a leer [ask] para obtener más información sobre cómo mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. Adicionalmente puedes realizar el [tour].